# How does Microsoft handle the fact that UTF-16 is a variable length encoding in their C++ standard library implementation

Tags: c++, utf-16

Having a variable length encoding is indirectly forbidden in the standard.

So I have several questions:

How is the following part of the standard handled?

> 17.3.2.1.3.3 Wide-character sequences
>
> A wide-character sequence is an array object (8.3.4) A that can be declared as T A[N], where T is type wchar_t (3.9.1), optionally qualified by any combination of const or volatile. The initial elements of the array have defined contents up to and including an element determined by some predicate. A character sequence can be designated by a pointer value S that designates its first element.
>
> The length of an NTWCS is the number of elements that precede the terminating null wide character. An empty NTWCS has a length of zero.

Questions:

`basic_string<wchar_t>`

- How is `operator[]` implemented and what does it return?

  - standard: `If pos < size(), returns data()[pos]. Otherwise, if pos == size(), the const version returns charT(). Otherwise, the behavior is undefined.`
- Does `size()` return the number of elements or the length of the string?

  - standard: `Returns: a count of the number of char-like objects currently in the string.`
- How does `resize()` work?

  - unrelated to standard, just what does it do
- How are the position in `insert()`, `erase()` and others handled?

`cwctype`

- Pretty much everything in here. How is the variable encoding handled?

`cwchar`

- `getwchar()` obviously can't return a whole platform-character, so how does this work?

Plus all the rest of the character function (the theme is the same).

Edit: I will be opening a bounty to get some confirmation. I want to get some clear answers or at least a clearer distribution of votes.

Edit: This is starting to get pointless. This is full of totally conflicting answers. Some of you talk about external encodings (I don't care about those, UTF-8 encoded will still be stored as UTF-16 once read into the string, the same for output), the rest simply contradicts each other. :-/

Comment: Perhaps you could elaborate on what you mean by the "fact" that their UTF-16 support is a variable length encoding (eg: an example where a string is encoded into more than 2 bytes per character). As far as I am aware, UTF-16 is treated as a fixed-length encoding in MS docs/code, but I'm not an expert, so an example would probably help.

Comment: A variable length encoding is by no means forbidden.  `wstring` does keep track of the number of elements, as you said, which it must know for allocation purposes, and is completely independent of encoding.  But elements != number of codepoints != number of glyphs, it's up to you to keep track of other measures of length.

Comment: @Nick This is interesting, where did you read that?

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: Maybe you are mixing concepts. Where in the standard have you seen that the *length of a `wchar_t` sequence is defined as the number of elements preceeding the `'\0'`? Both `string` and `wstring` support strings containing null characters.

Comment: @David I'm only talking about `wstring` in the second part of the question. First part is plain `wchar_t*`. Or `wchar_t s[constant];` to be precise.

Comment: @Ben: I think a variable-length encoding *is* more or less forbidden for wide strings (C style, this is). The standard defines bytes strings (ntbs), multibyte strings (ntmbs), and wide strings (ntwcs). It doesn't define multichar wide strings. But it also doesn't define how platform-specific APIs like the font renderer treat wide strings, so I absolutely agree with you that the number of glyphs is a completely independent thing. Basically, `wstring::size` *must* return the number of `wchar_t` in the string. If MS says, as an aside, that "really" it's UTF-16 not UCS-2, that makes no difference.

Comment: @Steve So what does `wcslen` return? How do you actually determine the string length on Windows?

Comment: `wcslen` returns the number of `wchar_t` before a 0. Windows' support for processing surrogate pairs is, AFAIK, rubbish. You're probably better off with UTF-8 and `_mbslen`.

Comment: I think this question is sorta confusing the issue (perhaps a title/tag edit is in order). The STL's handling of wchar_t strings doesn't handle variable length encodings for UTF-16, it ignores them (as other people have said). However, this is not a Microsoft issue, or a "problem" with the implementation of STL which they distribute: STL (and C++ for that matter) doesn't have any handling for variable length encoded strings (UTF-16 or otherwise). Are you asking what Windows API's are available to do this, or is this just about STL?

Comment: @Nick Well, that is a Microsoft issue, because if STL can't handle variable length encoding then to support STL you can't have variable encoding. That's kind of simple. The question is about C++ (STL mainly) but `wchar_t` as well. Windows API is irrelevant for me (the same goes for external encodings).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here's how Microsoft's STL implementation handles the variable-length encoding:

`basic_string<wchar_t>::operator[])(` can return a low or a high surrogate, in isolation.

`basic_string<wchar_t>::size()` returns the number of `wchar_t` objects. A surrogate pair (one Unicode character) uses two wchar_t's and therefore adds two to the size.

`basic_string<wchar_t>::resize()` can truncate a string in the middle of a surrogate pair.

`basic_string<wchar_t>::insert()` can insert in the middle of a surrogate pair.

`basic_string<wchar_t>::erase()` can erase either half of a surrogate pair.

In general, the pattern should be clear: the STL does not assume that a `std::wstring` is in UTF-16, nor enforce that it remains UTF-16.

Comment: How do you determine the string length if size() returns number of `wchar_t` objects? How do you safely insert(), erase(), etc? The "C" part of the standard library isn't supported in Windows for wide characters?

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: What would you want to do with that string length anyway? As for safely inserting, it's your responsibility anyway to find the correct place to insert text. Not only are there UTF-16 rules, but (human) languages add spelling and grammar rules that must be obeyed.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: If you consider the presence of combining marks in Unicode, you can only realize that the whole of Unicode is actually a variable-length encoding. What would you expect to happen if you have a string with the Unicode codepoints U+0041 U+0308 (LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A and COMBINING DIARESIS) and you try to insert the codepoint U+0030 (DIGIT ZERO) between them? Allog these codepoints are representable with a single element in UTF-16 and UCS-4.

Comment: @Bart You are talking about external encoding, that is irrelevant for me. I'm only talking about internal encoding.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: No, I am talking about *internal* coding. Even if your internal coding is UCS-4, it remains a variable-length coding due to the presence of combining marks in Unicode. There is just no way to encode every character (as a non-programmer would define such a thing) in a single codepoint.

Comment: @Bart No, you are using the word character in the external meaning *rendered character*.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: Then please enlighten me. What would the internal representation be for the character that is externally visible as an A with a line above it (LATIN CAPITAL A with COMBINING OVERLINE)?

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: And why would that make a difference for a user of a text-manipulation program? To the user it appears as a single glyph, so the program should treat it as a single character.

Comment: @Bart Of it matters to him. But this is high level semantic. How the heck you want to work with Glyphs, when you can't even work with Unicode characters. Plus Glyphs is something that has to be supported by the rendering platform, and if it is that that platform will obviously report correctly that the user is now insert at position X+2 (because the last Glyph consisted of two Unicode characters) and not X+1.

Comment: @MSalters: Did you perhaps mean "the STL does *not* assume that a std::string is UTF-16"?

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: You don't always have a rendering engine to help you deal with combining characters. The way to deal with them generally is to acknowledge that there is no such thing as a fixed-width text encoding (although you can get a long way if you put a restriction on the Unicode codepoints and normalisation forms that you accept, or just ignore their existence; The same as Microsoft does with their treatment of UTF-16 characters outside the BMP)

Comment: @Bart But you have no way of knowing if the rendering engine supports this (having a 3rd party/system rendering engine and having your own is equivalent for me). If the platform renders this as two separate characters (although it shouldn't), you need to treat it as two characters.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: No, again, I'm afraid. Even if the render engine draws `ä` in two steps, my editor should not allow me to insert an `e` in the middle to give me `aë`. That's just nonsense. To be clear: that is your responsibility as a programmer, not the STL's nor the rendering engine's responsibility.

Comment: @MSalters Again, I'm talking about the lower level of the code. If the top level indeed works this way, then you have to treat the `ä` as two separate characters.

Answer (score 9):

STL deals with strings as simply a wrapper for an array of characters therefore size() or length() on an STL string will tell you how many char or wchar_t elements it contains and not necessarily the number of printable characters it would be in a string.

Comment: So, they have implemented basic_string in such way that it can handle variable encoding (I will check for the collision I mentioned and report back) and ignore raw strings?

Comment: The absolutely correct OO way to handle variable-character-length strings would be to have a class represent a variable-length character and then have a vector of them. That would be a horribly inefficient implementation though. A better implementation is to store the array of elements in its raw form and then if you need to have another array of offsets to each character so you can find the nth character in constant time once it has been parsed through once. You can make this a wrapper, with state, including a state that the string is actually one-element-per-character throughout.

Comment: I'm not really interested in the correct way. For me the correct way is to use variable encoding on input and output only. What I'm asking is how Microsoft handles the fact, that they actually have a variable length encoding for `wchar_t` and consequently for `wstring`.

Answer (score 9):

Assuming that you're talking about the `wstring` type, there would be no handling of the encoding - it just deals with `wchar_t` elements without knowing anything about the encoding. It's just a sequence of `wchar_t`'s.  You'll need to deal with encoding issues using functionality of other functions.

Comment: AFAIK this is right. Not sure whether UTF-16 offers multiple ways to encode the same code point, in the way UTF-8 does. Even if it does, as long as functions like `wstring::operator==` don't "unfold" the encoding, and in that case returns true if and only if the strings consist of the same sequence of `wchar_t`, the implementation is compliant. It's as if the encoding was UCS-2. The standard doesn't say anything about whether functions like `fopen` are allowed to treat "different" wide strings as representing the same file, so they're allowed to treat the name as variable-length encoded.

Comment: You need to deal with the fact the wchar_t != one platform character.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: UTF-16 uses surrogate pairs (2 16 bit values) for any character outside the BMP (past U+10000). You're not allowed to use surrogate pairs for BMP characters. Essentially, it enforces a canonical representation in the same way as UTF-8 does, by mandating the shortest possible encoding. Besides, the strings used by `fopen` are open to platform interpretation anyway. C and C++ don't even specify whether they're case-sensitive.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: deal with it how? As far as the C++ language is concerned, the execution wide character set is `int16_t` (or `uint16_t`, I can't remember whether MS's `wchar_t` is signed). Implementation-defined meanings of strings are a whole separate issue, and it's only here that MS comes in and says, "it's UTF-16". Can you give an example of some code which behaves differently with Microsoft's definition of a wide character, from what the standard allows?

Comment: @Steve The standard actually doesn't care about he underlying type. What I'm searching for is what MSalters posted in his answer. If it's true, then I need to know how to walk around these semantics.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: AFAIK everything in MSalters' answer is true. It should be easy enough for you to confirm that by running a few tests, if you doubt it. I would say that the way to deal with it is to treat wide strings as an output format (to Windows APIs), and don't modify them in that format, but I'm not a Windows programmer so I can't swear to you that MS doesn't provide a better way

Comment: @Steve I would if I could. I don't have a Windows machine anywhere near me. Actually I do, but I don't have admin rights on Faculty machines.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: "The standard actually doesn't care" - OK, I suppose what I really meant was, "as far as the language is concerned, the execution wide character set has the the range of values that `int16_t` has". You're right, it doesn't care what the type "really is", but it cares what the values are. So, what I mean is what MSalters says - on MS compilers, the language "thinks" that a high surrogate is a character.

Comment: @Steve Yeah, thanks. I just want to get all of this totally 100% clear.

Answer (score 4):

Two things:

1. There is no "Microsoft STL implementation". The C++ Standard Library shipped with Visual C++ is licensed from Dinkumware.
2. The current C++ Standard knows nothing about Unicode and its encoding forms. std::wstring is merely a container for wchar_t units which happen to be 16-bit on Windows. In practice, if you want to store a UTF-16 encoded string into a wstring, just take into account that you are really storing code units and not code points.

Comment: There certainly *is* a Microsoft STL implementation. It may be licensed, but it's also modified, so it's not the original Dinkumware implementation anymore (and even if it was, it's still part of the Visual Studio product). Also, the current C++ standard *does* know something about Unicode: ISO 10646 is a normative reference, and universal character names are interpreted as Unicode. It's also reasonable to assume that C99's `__STDC_ISO_10646__`, if defined, has the same meaning in a C++ implementation (even though C++98 does not mention it).

Comment: the Microsoft STL implementation is now also opensourced https://github.com/microsoft/STL

Answer (score 0):

MSVC stores `wchar_t` in `wstring`s.  These can be interpreted as unicode 16 bit words, or anything else really.

If you want to get access to unicode characters or glyphs, you'll have to process said raw string by the unicode standard.  You probably also want to handle common corner cases without breaking.

Here is a sketch of such a library.  It is about half as memory efficient as it could be, but it does give you in-place access to unicode glyphs in a `std::string`.  It relies on having a decent `array_view` class, but you want to write one of those anyhow:

```
struct unicode_char : array_view<wchar_t const> {
  using array_view<wchar_t const>::array_view<wchar_t const>;

  uint32_t value() const {
    if (size()==1)
      return front();
    Assert(size()==2);
    if (size()==2)
    {
      wchar_t high = front()-0xD800;
      wchar_T low = back()-0xDC00;
      return (uint32_t(high)<<10) + uint32_t(low);
    }
    return 0; // error
  }
  static bool is_high_surrogate( wchar_t c ) {
    return (c >= 0xD800 && c <= 0xDBFF);
  }
  static bool is_low_surrogate( wchar_t c ) {
    return (c >= 0xDC00 && c <= 0xDFFF);
  }
  static unicode_char extract( array_view<wchar_t const> raw )
  {
    if (raw.empty())
      return {};
    if (raw.size()==1)
      return raw;
    if (is_high_surrogate(raw.front()) && is_low_surrogate(*std::next(raw.begin())))
      return {raw.begin(), raw.begin()+2);
    return {raw.begin(), std::next(raw.begin())};
  }
};
static std::vector<unicode_char> as_unicode_chars( array_view<wchar_t> raw )
{
  std::vector<unicode_char> retval;
  retval.reserve( raw.size() ); // usually 1:1
  while(!raw.empty())
  {
    retval.push_back( unicode_char::extract(raw) );
    Assert( retval.back().size() <= raw.size() );
    raw = {raw.begin() + retval.back().size(), raw.end()};
  }
  return retval;
}
struct unicode_glyph {
  std::array< unicode_char, 3 > buff;
  std::size_t count=0;
  unicode_char const* begin() const {
    return buff.begin();
  }
  unicode_char const* end() const {
    return buff.begin()+count;
  }
  std::size_t size() const { return count; }
  bool empty() { return size()==0; }
  unicode_char const& front() const { return *begin(); }
  unicode_char const& back() const { return *std::prev(end()); }
  array_view< unicode_char const > chars() const { return {begin(), end()}; }
  array_view< wchar_t const > wchars() const {
    if (empty()) return {};
    return { front().begin(), back().end() };
  }

  void append( unicode_char next ) {
    Assert(count<3);
    buff[count++] = next;
  }
  unicode_glyph() {}

  static bool is_diacrit(unicode_char c) const {
    auto v = c.value();
    return is_diacrit(v);
  }
  static bool is_diacrit(uint32_t v) const {
    return
      ((v >= 0x0300) && (v <= 0x0360))
    || ((v >= 0x1AB0) && (v <= 0x1AFF))
    || ((v >= 0x1DC0) && (v <= 0x1DFF))
    || ((v >= 0x20D0) && (v <= 0x20FF))
    || ((v >= 0xFE20) && (v <= 0xFE2F));
  }
  static size_t diacrit_count(unicode_char c) const {
    auto v = c.value();
    if (is_diacrit(v))
      return 1 + ((v >= 0x035C)&&(v<=0x0362));
    else
      return 0;
  }
  static unicode_glyph extract( array_view<const unicode_char> raw ) {
    unicode_glyph retval;
    if (raw.empty())
      return retval;
    if (raw.size()==1)
    {
      retval.append(raw.front());
      return retval;
    }
    retval.count = diacrit_count( *std::next(raw.begin()) )+1;
    std::copy( raw.begin(), raw.begin()+retval.count, retval.buff.begin() );
    return retval;
  }
};
static std::vector<unicode_glyph> as_unicode_glyphs( array_view<unicode_char> raw )
{
  std::vector<unicode_glyph> retval;
  retval.reserve( raw.size() ); // usually 1:1
  while(!raw.empty())
  {
    retval.push_back( unicode_glyph::extract(raw) );
    Assert( retval.back().size() <= raw.size() );
    raw = {raw.begin() + retval.back().size(), raw.end()};
  }
  return retval;
}
static std::vector<unicode_glyph> as_unicode_glyphs( array_view<wchar_t> raw )
{
  return as_unicode_glyphs( as_unicode_chars( raw ) );
}
```

a smarter bit of code would generate the `unicode_char`s and `unicode_glyph`s on the fly with a factory iterator of some kind.  A more compact implementation would keep track of the fact that the end pointer of the previous and begin pointer of the next are always identical, and alias them together.  Another optimization would be to use a small object optimization on glyph based off the assumption that most glyphs are one character, and use dynamic allocation if they are two.

Note that I treat CGJ as a standard diacrit, and the double-diacrits as a set of 3 characters that form one (unicode), but half-diacrits don't merge things into one glyph.  These are all questionable choices.

This was written in a bout of insomnia.  Hope it at least somewhat works.